# Navigate to Sharepoint Site and Export Data

Tags: excel, sharepoint, vba

I know a little about Excel VBA but this is a little over my head (may not even be possible).

Is there a way to write code to;

- Navigate to a sharepoint web addresss
- In the 'Library' menu at the top it is selected
- 'Export Data' is clicked

Basically mimicking how an actual person would interact to achieve this?

I've looked everywhere but can't find anything which is making me think it is not possible, but have seen things 'not thought possible' achieved through this site so thought I'd give it a shot.

Can anyone help me with this please?

Comment: So I have tried IE Automation but I am very new to VBA and it's overly complicated for my level.
What I've been reading is to somehow use the following code from the site I am accessing but it just doesn't seem to work for example code I have tried;
<span class="ms-cui-ctl-mediumlabel" unselectable="on">Export to Excel</span>

Comment: I basically want it to load the page "which I can do" and then click the "Export to Excel" button in the toolbar on the SharePoint site but can't get that to happen, the page loads then nothing. Can anyone show me how I would achieve this? Tutorials say to call the class or tag but can't determine what is what. I'm sorry lame I know but I am very new to all this :(

Answer (score 0):

If you want a macro in Excel that works with a webpage like a person would, you can use IE automation. There you can tell IE to go to a specified URL, press explicit buttons, enter some text, wait for the page to load, etc. You'll find plenty guides for "excel vba ie automation".